# Run time error when opening word document with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhA39.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
'Checks if file exists if not creates one
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileExists As String
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc
    strFileName = "C:\Users\jtrayton\Documents\Ideas\Monthly Reporting Spreadsheet\Word Doc Test.docx"
    strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
   If strFileExists = "" Then
    MsgBox "The selected file doesn't exist"
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jtrayton\Documents\Ideas\Monthly Reporting 
Spreadsheet\Report Template.docx")
    'objDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="##Title##", ReplaceWith:="Client Name", _
    'Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Users\jtrayton\Documents\Ideas\Monthly Reporting Spreadsheet\Word Doc Test.docx")
   Else
    MsgBox "The selected file exists"
End If
End Sub
```

When I run the above code it takes a while to run then break when it tries to open the word document. I have run it successfully before but for some reason it breaks every now and then. Any help would be great:)

Comment: Does the file in `Open` method exist? Try `Dir("C:\Users\jtrayton\Documents\Ideas\Monthly Reporting 
Spreadsheet\Report Template.docx")`

Comment: Hi, yes the file exists, if I copy and paste the path in file explorer the file opens

Comment: But can you open it without any prompt? Is it protected with password?

Comment: Oh it opens in protected view... could that be the issue?

Comment: try turning off protecred view for that document and try again, i suggest you can debug too by making `objWord` visible so that you can see if it really opens the document `objWord.Visible = True`